# loading a dylib in firemonkey

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, firemonkey, dylib

One of my first steps in converting my app to firemonkey is converting some dlls that my app uses.

Can anyone point me towards some documentation that would help me with this process? The dll's have been designed with cross platform in mind (using as much boost stuff as possible) so once I get my head around it im not too worried about the internals of the dlls.

A couple of specific questions...

1. On the delphi side LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress are part of the wind32 API. I cant find documentation for other platforms?
2. In XCode I have created a dynamic library project and can see how the "GCC Visibility" works for exported classes. I assume its the same for just extported functions. How do you set the export type. i.e. Extern "C"?

Thanks in advance.

Martin

Comment: Give a look through http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html - I suspect the section titled "Dynamic loading and un-loading of shared libraries using libdl" would be of interest.

Answer (score 6):

The `LoadLibrary` and related functions for OSX are defined in the Sysutils unit.

```
function LoadLibrary(ModuleName: PChar): HMODULE;    
function FreeLibrary(Module: HMODULE): LongBool;
function GetProcAddress(Module: HMODULE; Proc: PChar): Pointer;
function GetModuleHandle(ModuleName: PChar): HMODULE;
function GetPackageModuleHandle(PackageName: PChar): HMODULE;
```

For embarcadero documentation about this topic the try this link [`Cross-Platform Shared Libraries.`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Cross-Platform_Shared_Libraries)